# Error: install Mustache PHP Extension error

Tags: php

When I install "mustache" PHP extension with "pecl install mustache" command I get a error like "configure: error: libmustache not found" .

My PHP version is : PHP Version 7.2.11
My Mac version is : High Sierra (10.13.6)

[Error Detail is here][1]

```
`checking for libmustache files... configure: error: libmustache not 
found
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/mustache/configure --with-php- 
config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config' failed`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a php extension, but you are missing the underlying library. Install libmustache first, with (as it seems you are on macOS):

```
brew install libmustache
```

See https://github.com/jbboehr/libmustache for reference

Comment: When I run that commad I get error like that ; Error: No available formula with the name "libmustache"

Comment: @talha your brew manager could be outdated. Try to catch up with `brew update` and `brew upgrade`